# Would a long running sql command using connection pooling cause other command using that same connection to error?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connection-pooling

I'm trying to trouble shoot the dreaded Timeout expired sql error.  I've noticed a pattern that is as follows.

1. User kicks off long running sql count on large table
2. Error - Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
3. Followed by 10 + Errors - Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Third step error occurs in a service where first sql command is from a web project.  So is it possible that because the connection is broken because of #1 other connections fail?  If so is there a way to exclude certain commands from using connection pooling?  Thanks!

UPDATE

-I'm using MS SQL 2012 and the Entity framework.
-I've set the entire db transaction level to READ UNCOMMITTED since we don't care about dirty reads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is locking out all of the other statements at the database level. Are you using SQL Server? In my experience SQL Server locks tables in so many scenarios that the DBA always reverted to dirty reads--any other locking configuration caused too much contention.

To get around this problem you can do the long running work in a temporary table, and then copy to the real table when the work is done.

Comment: I thought I had set READ UNCOMMITTED globally but it turns out I didn't.  Thanks!